# Why am i getting a stacked text label in table view swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Why am I getting a text that stacked like this?
I know i can just delete the 'lbl' text from the inspector, but I don't believe I should get something like this.
what did i miss?
thankyou in advance

[image]

here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

let name = [
"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return name.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bodyCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = name[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

}
```

Comment: There must be some other label added in your cell.

Comment: I'm having this same issue and can't figure it out. Where is "OutletClass"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it programmatically:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let tableView = UITableView()
let name = [
"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "bodyCell")

    // add your tableView and add constraint
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return name.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bodyCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = name[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: Its a `UITableViewController`. You don't need to set the `dataSource` and if the `cell` is inside the `storyboard` itself, there is no need to register it as well. And as you can see from the screenshot, the code is working fine and the text is set on the cell's `textLabel`.

Comment: Well, first of all that's not my question. And secondly it is specified in the question already `class ViewController: UITableViewController {`

Comment: ok so i still can't figure this out, it's a bummer I usually can replace whatever the text label in the storyboard. i've double checked and there's only 1 label there.
my guess is in this part: `cell.textLabel?.text = name[indexPath.row]` might create another text label?
i have connected the outlet in another class, however, I can't access it through `cell.`

Comment: Hi Aldo, are you Italian?

Answer (score 0):

So I just figured out my self,

I need to cast it after `dequeueReusableCell`
so it looks like this:

`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bodyCell", for: indexPath) as! OutletClass`

so the OutletClass is the class where I connected the label.
well at least that's my case.